# React Dom Routes not working as intended, changes the path but nothing on the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am making a webplatform working with the OpenLibrary API, I am pulling data from the subjects then when you click on one of the books in the subjects, I want to be taken to a page called 'Book' where I display the data.
Now I have set up my Routes (i think they're correct), but when I click one of the items in the list, it doesn't do anything, it changes the URL to the route I set up, but it doesn't take me to the Book component where I display the data. Now, I haven't posted my Book.js file because it just has test code in it to see if I can get to the component. Any help will be appreciated!

Here are some snippets of my code:

App.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

import Works from "./components/Works";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [subjects, setSubjects] = useState([]);
  const [worksDetails, setWorkDetails] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const url = "https://openlibrary.org/subjects/animals.json?limit=10";
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(url)
      .then((response) => {
        setSubjects(response.data);
        setWorkDetails(response.data.works);
        setIsLoading(true);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, []);

  if (!isLoading) {
    return <p>Loading...</p>;
  } else {
    return (
      <>
        <Navbar />
        <div className="contentHeader">
          <h1 className="subjectHeader" style={{ padding: "10px" }}>
            Subject: {subjects.name.toUpperCase()}
          </h1>
          <h1 className="workHeader" style={{ padding: "10px" }}>
            Work Count: {subjects.work_count.toLocaleString()}
          </h1>
        </div>
        <div>
          <Works works={worksDetails} />
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Works.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Book from "../routes/Book";

const Works = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div>
        <div className="heading">
          {props.works.map((work) => {
            return (
              <Link to={`/book/${work.key}`} element={<Book />} key={work.key}>
                <ul>{work.title}</ul>
              </Link>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Works;
```

Index.js

```
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import App from "./App";
import Book from "./routes/Book";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="*" element={<App />} />
      <Route path="/book" element={<Book />}>
        <Route path=":bookId" element={<Book />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

When you use

```
<Route path="/book" element={<Book />}>
  <Route path=":bookId" element={<Book />} />
</Route>
```

The `Route` component is expecting `Book` to render an `Outlet` component for the nested `Route` component. This doesn't appear to be the UX you are going for though. The outer route is matched and rendered, but then because there's no outlet the inner route rendering the *actual* `Book` component you want with the param isn't rendered at all.

It turns out that in the fetched data that `work.key` isn't just an id, but a nested route value it seems, i.e. something like `"key": "/works/OL138052W"`, so the UI is computing a malformed route (*`"/book//works/OL138052W"`*) ***and*** linking to a route that doesn't exist.

## Solution

`` to={`/book${work.key}`} `` is the path you are linking to, note the removal of the `"/"` between "book" and the injected `work.key` value:

```
<Link key={work.key} to={`/book${work.key}`}>
  <ul>{work.title}</ul>
</Link>
```

Then the should render one of the following:

```
<Route path="/book/works/:bookId" element={<Book />} />
```

or

```
<Route path="/book/works">
  <Route path=":bookId" element={<Book />} /> // "/book/works/:bookId"
</Route>
```

[image: Edit react-dom-routes-not-working-as-intended-changes-the-path-but-nothing-on-the-pa]

If you don't want to mess with this `work.key` value then you may want to select one of the other properties, so long as they provide sufficient uniqueness for identification purposes.

Comment: Hmm, I tried this out, and the component still isn't rendering... also. When I change the Route path to the main App in the index file from a * to just '/', and i click one of the items, it says "No routes matched location "/book//works/OL138052W". but if I keep it as '*', nothing happens either

Comment: Also, if I manually type in the pathing in the url with /book the component does load, so could that be something to do with the <Link to > I have set up?

Comment: @lhunter50 `"/book//works/OL138052W"` isn't a route path you render a route for, so I'm not surprised at the error message there. I'm updating my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your Route should look like this:

```
<Route path="/book/:bookId" element={<Book />}>
```

Comment: React Router 6 allows you to do nested routes like his example